# Get computational graph / expression of symbolic matrix differentiation

Tags: python, symbolic-math

I want to write some custom CUDA kernels for neural networks to speed up computations, but I don't want to spend time differentiating tensor expressions by hand if there are packages that can do it automatically.

Is there a python package that can show expression for symbolic matrix differentiation?

I know `sympy` can do it for non-matrix expressions like this:

```
def func(x):
    return 1 / x

arg_symbols = sp.symbols(inspect.getfullargspec(func).args)
sym_func = func(*arg_symbols)
s = ''
for arg in arg_symbols:
    s += '{}\n'.format(arg, sp.Lambda(arg_symbols, sym_func.diff(arg)))
# this is what I need:
print(s)
>>> Lambda(x, -1/x**2)
```

I know `autograd` package can compute the derivatives of matrix expressions

> After the function is evaluated, autograd has a list of all operations
>   that were performed and which nodes they depended on. This is the
>   computational graph of the function evaluation. To compute the
>   derivative, we simply apply the rules of differentiation to each node
>   in the graph.

But is there a way to get this differentiation computational graph from it or some similar package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some severe differences between the packages you cited. The differences are the reason why you cannot get (AFAIK) directly the computational graph from  an automatic differentiation library, but you can get it from a symbolic based one.

In short:

- numerical differentiation: `numpy` is enough
- symbolic differentiation: `sympy`
- automatic differentiation: `autograd` is one example

There are three kind of differentiations methods:

- numerical differentiation: this evaluates `Delta(f(x)) / Delta(x)` where `Delta(x)` is a small difference that represents  variation of `x` while remaining in the domain of `f`. This is not what you need. You don't need a package for this.
- symbolic differentiation: is based upon the construction of a graph that represents the symbolic applications of function (I have an article on the implementation of symbolic engine in Ruby [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711017300146)). In this case the differentiation is performed through a recursive application of the chain derivation rule:

  ```
  f(g(x))' = f'(g(x)) * g'(x)
  ```

  When this rule is applied to the whole symbolic graph, what results is a newer symbolic graph with the derivative. The advantage lies in the fact that the derivative is exact, but for very complex graph, the final derivative graph may be non-tractable (exceeds memory limits or stack limits for too deep recursion). **In python `sympy` implements this kind of derivation**. On the other side, if you have a graph of the derivative you can perform operations on it, such as simplifications or substitutions.

  ```
  from sympy import *
  import numpy as np

  x = symbol('x')
  f = 1 / x
  df = diff(f, x)
  print(df)
  # -1/x**2

  ldf = lambdify((x), df)

  # Now ldf is a lambda
  x_ary = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 
    [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
  ])
  y_ary = ldf(x_ary)

  print(xn.shape)
  # (2, 2, 3)
  print(y_ary)
  # array([[[-1.        , -0.25      , -0.11111111],
  #         [-1.        , -0.25      , -0.11111111]],
  #        [[-1.        , -0.25      , -0.11111111],
  #         [-1.        , -0.25      , -0.11111111]]])
  ```

  as you can see it works with `numpy`, but it covers some of the basic examples not everything, and in fact `sympy.matrix` alongside with `sympy.symbol` should be used for particular graph (for example: I don't think it can handle `diff(x.T A x, x) = x.T A + A x)` directly).

  It is possible also to [export the graph as `C` code](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/codegen.html), but it has some limited capabilities and for your application you must certainly modify the result:

  ```
  from scipy.utilities.codegen import codegen

  [(cf, cc), (hf, hc)] = codegen(("df", df), "C", "df")

  print(hc, cc)
  ```

  Prints out:

```c
/*****************************************************
 *      Code generated with sympy 1.1.1              *
 *  See http://www.sympy.org/ for more information.  *
 *      This file is part of 'project'               *
 *****************************************************/

#ifndef PROJECT__DIFF__H
#define PROJECT__DIFF__H

double df(double x);

#endif

/*****************************************************
 *      Code generated with sympy 1.1.1              *
 *  See http://www.sympy.org/ for more information.  *
 *      This file is part of 'project'               *
 *****************************************************/
#include "diff.h"
#include <math.h>

double df(double x) {   
  double df_result;
  df_result = -1/pow(x, 2);
  return df_result;   
}
```

- **automatic differentiation** is what is done through `autograd`. In this case the best of both world is united. From one side it is not necessary to explicitly evaluate the graph, on the other side you cannot perform further operation on the derived function, while keeping the derivative exact. This is done (usually) by augmenting the `float` definition with an additional field (something like `float[2]` or more), where the additional field contains the derivative. For example in an automatic differentiation environment, the `sin` function may be overloaded with:

  ```
  def sin(x):
       return [sin(x[0]), x[1] * cos(x[0])]
  ```

  but as you can understand in this way, no computational graph is available, but you get directly the value of the exact derivative along `x` (all functions must be overloaded). I have an example more complete (in C lang, using only macros) [here](https://gist.github.com/MatteoRagni/5ba80271a98bfd61388f5fca27dc0e7d). **Notice that internally Tensorflow uses automatic differentiation instead of symbolic one but suggests user to directly provide an "explicit version" that handles numerical instabilities!**. Automatic differentiation does not handles numerical instability usually.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to extract the derivative graph in some handy form from any of these packages? (I need it to hardcode it in CUDA etc)

Comment: You can export C code, that with minimal modification can be employed in cuda

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how to do it?

Comment: it is in the answer